# nginx: Rewrite PHP does not work

Tags: php, nginx, rewrite

<strike>I've a Suffix Proxy installed and I'm using the following rewrite with wildcard subdomain DNS on:</strike>

```
location / {
     if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last;
        break;
     }
}
```

My suffix proxy has the following URL format:
(subdomain and/or domain + domain extension to proxy).proxy.org/(request-uri to proxy)

I've this php code in my index.php:

```
if(preg_match('#([\w\.-]+)\.example\.com(.+)#', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $match)) {
    header('Location: http://example.com/browse.php?u=http://'.$match[1].$match[2]);
    die;
}
```

But when requested a page with a .php extension I'll get a 404 not found error:

```
http://www.php.net.proxy.org/docs.php - HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
http://www.utexas.edu.proxy.org/learn/php/ex3.php - HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

But everything else is working (also index.php is working):

```
http://php.net.proxy.org/index.php - HTTP/1.1 200 OK
http://www.php-scripts.com.proxy.org/php_diary/example2.php3 - HTTP/1.1 200 OK
http://www.utexas.edu.proxy.org/learn/php/ex3.phps - HTTP/1.1 200 OK
http://www.w3schools.com.proxy.org/html/default.asp - HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Somebody has an answer? I don't know why it's not working, on apache it's working fine.

Thanks in advance.

I've removed the location and now it's working perfectly:

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
     rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last;
     break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not fully understand your question. But, it looks like you may want to add try_files in your location block, something like this...

```
location / {
     if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last;
        break;
     }

     try_files $uri =404;
}
```

I hope this helps.